# Bitcoin Armory Difference in GPG Output

Tags: armory

The section "Verifying Downloaded Files' at http://bitcoinarmory.com/download/ says that I should see the following output after running GPG:

```
$ gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 98832223
gpg: requesting key 98832223 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 98832223: public key "Alan C. Reiner (Armory Signing Key) <alan.reiner@gmail.com>"
```

However when I ran it, I got:

```
gpg: key 98832223: public key "Alan C. Reiner (Offline Signing Key) <alan@bitcoinarmory.com>" imported
```

instead. A link I found on btcarmory.org (http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/pks/lookup?search=Armory+Signing) has a result that implies that these two outputs are acceptable, but can someone please confirm that this is true?

Is the difference in the GPG output a concern? I only ask because of how intensely it is suggested to do this stuff! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is fine. The key fingerprint is the same. Alan merely has several uid records in this key.

See for yourself:

```
$ gpg --list-key 98832223
pub   4096R/98832223 2012-02-28
uid                  Alan C. Reiner (Offline Signing Key) <alan@bitcoinarmory.com>
uid                  Alan C. Reiner (Armory Signing Key) <etotheipi@gmail.com>
uid                  Alan C. Reiner (Armory Signing Key) <alan.reiner@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/DE6B2D74 2012-02-28
```

GnuPG simply chose to show you one of the other, completely valid uids for this key.

Comment: You could email him and advise him to update what it says on the site to eliminate the confusion that spawned this question.